# Checking only when it is .tolist()

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, matching

I have to put a column in a list to be able to find matches.

I am trying to create a table "mytable" that gets data from going through each row of another table "table_main" and if it meets the condition, add rows to mytable. I have other tables as well, e.g. "table3" all DataFrame.

I wrote it like:

```
mytable = {'column1' :[] , 'column2':[] , 'column3': [] , 'column4':[]}

for index, row in table_main.itterrows():
   if row['apple'] not in table3['codes'] and row['apple']!= "07":
       mytable['column1'].append("2024")
       mytable['column2'].append(str(row['number']))
       mytable['column3'].append(str(row['apple']))
       mytable['column4'].append("first condition")
```

but it can't understand row['apple'] values exist in table3['codes']. I tried to put str( before them still not working. Only works when I put table3['codes'].tolist() but I don't want to do it.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: What is `table_main`? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
mytable = {'column1': [], 'column2': [], 'column3': [], 'column4': []}

for index, row in table_main.iterrows():
    if (row['apple'] not in table3['codes'].values) and (row['apple'] != "07"):
        mytable['column1'].append("2024")
        mytable['column2'].append(str(row['number']))
        mytable['column3'].append(str(row['apple']))
        mytable['column4'].append("first condition")
```

Updated code For Matching row:

```
mytable = {'column1': [], 'column2': [], 'column3': [], 'column4': []}

for index, row in table_main.iterrows():
    # Your condition to find matching rows
    if row['apple'] in table3['codes'].values and row['apple'] != "07":
        mytable['column1'].append("2024")
        mytable['column2'].append(str(row['number']))
        mytable['column3'].append(str(row['apple']))
        mytable['column4'].append("another condition")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works with adding values.
in another condition that is somehow similar, I want to find the matching and then add rows if  
'''

Comment: You're Welcome, @Melika02. I have updated answer for matching row as well, please check

Comment: Thank you!
in another condition that is somehow similar, I want to find the matching and then add rows if the third column in table3 has the value "Buzz" in the matching row. Again it shows all the matching columns only and does not check for the third column. Here is my code:

if pd.notnull(row['apple']) and (row['apple'] == (table3['names'].values) and table3['third_column'] == 'Buzz'):

Comment: Syntax issue in your condition. try this : if pd.notnull(row['apple']) and ((row['apple'] == table3['names'].values) & (table3['third_column'] == 'Buzz')).any():

Comment: I don't know why it is working in some conditions, but not working in others. For example, if I add more conditions to it like:
if pd.notnull(row['apple']) and (row['license'] != '12') and ((row['apple'] == table3['names'].values) & (table3['third_column'] != 'Buzz')).any() : 

it again shows all the results which is not correct.

Comment: What you are expecting as output?

Comment: as an output for this condition, I expect it to iterate in  table_main and find rows that meet the condition and for each row in table_main that meet the condition, it adds one row to mytable and fill it according to:
        mytable['column1'].append("2024")
        mytable['column2'].append(str(row['number']))
        mytable['column3'].append(str(row['apple']))
        mytable['column4'].append("another condition")

according to my files, it must add no rows while it shows too many rows instead.

Answer (score 0):

`table3['codes']` is a column data type, so in order to find element in this data type so you need to use method which look of element which this data type support or transform the values to another datatype where you can use `in` to check values

So make the changes

```
if row['apple'] not in table3['codes'] and row['apple']!= "07":
```

to

```
if row['apple'] not in table3['codes'].values and row['apple']!= "07":
```